# Does Moralis "Get NFTs by Wallet" API support ERC-1155?

Tags: tokens, nft, erc-1155, moralis, api

I am using [this service](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-wallet-nfts) from Moralis to retrieve all the NFTs that a wallet has.

Does this support `ERC-1155`? I know these tokens are semi-fungible so they are not exactly NFTs, but I was hoping I can get their information from this service.

Does anybody know if they retrieve `"contract_type": "ERC1155"` and `"amount"` greater than `"1"` for these type of tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does support ERC1155 NFT, so all ERC1155 and ERC721, including non-standard NFT (e.g. Cryptopunk) will be fetched and indexed with this API.

Hope this helps~

Comment: Thanks! So the fields I mentioned are the correct ones for ERC1155's?

Comment: Yes correct! and for NFT that has `"contract_type": "ERC1155"` it is allowed to have `amount` value above 1 since it is semi-fungible, for ERC721 tho it can only be 1.

Comment: Thanks, dude!!!